# Trying to learn Rails and can not open config/routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am trying to delve into Rails as a complete beginner and at the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) they say I need to open the file "config/routes.rb" in the editor (I am using Atom).

When I go to File->Open and then search for "config/routes.rb", I can not find anything. I do not know where to find this file.

I feel like starting Rails even with some Ruby experience is very challenging. I just want to get even *one* thing up and running.

Comment: Have you generated your rails project yet?

Comment: The only thing that is running so far as I can tell in the sense of the word generated is that when I go to the localhost:3000 I see the smoke test about riding ruby.

Comment: Okay, so you have your project. In your terminal you should be able to `cd` into the directory, which should share the name of your project. You should then be able to run `atom config/routes.rb`

Answer (score 1):

If you are following that guide, you will have generated your new project from the command line. After running that command, a new directory will be created in the same directory where you generated your project. The new directory will have the same name you passed to `rails new`. This is the directory that is going to be home to your project.

The config directory will be inside *that* directory.

```
$ rails new my_project
```

This will output lots of stuff. It will generate what you need to get started.

This is what your new rails project top-level structure should look like:

```
$ ls -alh my_project

drwxr-xr-x   3 brennan  staff   102B Jan 29 16:10 .bundle
-rw-r--r--   1 brennan  staff   455B Jan 29 16:10 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--   1 brennan  staff   1.1K Jan 29 16:10 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--   1 brennan  staff   2.7K Jan 29 16:11 Gemfile.lock    
-rw-r--r--   1 brennan  staff   478B Jan 29 16:10 README.rdoc
-rw-r--r--   1 brennan  staff   254B Jan 29 16:10 Rakefile
drwxr-xr-x   8 brennan  staff   272B Jan 29 16:10 app
drwxr-xr-x   5 brennan  staff   170B Jan 29 16:10 bin
drwxr-xr-x  10 brennan  staff   340B Jan 29 16:10 config #HERE IS YOUR CONFIG DIRECTORY 
-rw-r--r--   1 brennan  staff   154B Jan 29 16:10 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x   3 brennan  staff   102B Jan 29 16:10 db
drwxr-xr-x   4 brennan  staff   136B Jan 29 16:10 lib
drwxr-xr-x   3 brennan  staff   102B Jan 29 16:10 log
drwxr-xr-x   7 brennan  staff   238B Jan 29 16:10 public
drwxr-xr-x   9 brennan  staff   306B Jan 29 16:10 test
drwxr-xr-x   3 brennan  staff   102B Jan 29 16:10 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   3 brennan  staff   102B Jan 29 16:10 vendor
```

To make it easy, you can even open the whole project in atom with one command:

```
$ atom my_project
```

And you should be good to go!

Comment: Awesome. I was able to figure my way around it from the comment you left. One thing I was struggling with was trying to figure out how to enter commands after I started the server. This is where my problem was. I thought it was just doing it without giving feedback. I didn't realize I had to start a new tab/window of terminal.

Comment: Yeah, once you start the server, it's going to take control of that terminal unless you send it to the background or open a new tab. Also, please don't  forget to accept correct answers. It will not only help me, but will make people more inclined to offer help in the future